# ctypes POINTER(c_void_p) in a callback function

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I am currently facing a problem with ctypes. I have a C function foo such that:

```
void** foo(int);
```

I have to define a callback function for the foo function. So:

```
FOO_FUNC = CFUNCTYPE(POINTER(c_void_p), c_int)
foo_c = lib.foo
foo.argtypes = [c_int]
foo.restype = POINTER(c_void_p)
```

Unfortunately, while calling a function taking this callback function as argument, it gives the error:
    `TypeError: invalid result type for callback function`

I can't see the problem... Can anyone help me? 
Thanks

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code? Like the part where you actually pass in the callback function?

Comment: I've actually highly simplified the situation. So i'm not sure it is gonna help you to see that part. I thought the problem came from the POINTER(c_void_p) type, that might be non accepted. The part you asked is something like: result = my_function_c(FOO_FUNC(foo_c))

Answer (score 1):

Use `c_void_p` instead of `POINTER(c_void_p)`.  I think that should fix it.  Also note that you cannot use composite types as callback return types: [Issue5710](http://bugs.python.org/issue5710)